# Why is this function calling twice?

Tags: javascript, function

New to JS and still learning, but writing a calculator for school. I'm pretty much done and worked out all the kinks, but having a small problem I can't pinpoint. Any help is appreciated. Everything works, but the "answer" function is being called twice in a row. The first time it shows up, everything is right, but the second time it shows one of my variables as undefined. I obviously only need it to show up right the first time. What am I missing?

```
var number1;
var number2;
var operator;
var total;
var runagain;

function main()
{
    inputNumbers();
    assignment();
    answer();
    keepgoing();
}

function inputNumbers()
{
    number1 = parseInt(prompt("Enter Your First Number", 0));
    while(isNaN(number1))
    {
        alert("You did not enter a valid number. Please try again.");
        number1 = parseInt(prompt("Enter Your First Number", 0));
    }
    number2 = parseInt(prompt("Enter Your Second Number", 0));
    while(isNaN(number2))
    {
        alert("You did not enter a valid number. Please try again.");
        number2 = parseInt(prompt("Enter Your Second Number", 0));
    }
}

function assignment()
{
    operator = parseInt(prompt("Enter a '1' for addition\n" + "Enter a '2' for subtraction\n" + "Enter a '3' for multiplication\n" + "Enter a '4' for division\n" + "Enter a '5' for modulus/remainder"));

    if(operator == 1)
    {
        add();
        operator = " + ";
        answer(operator);
    }

    else if(operator == 2)
    {
        subtract();
        operator = " - ";
        answer(operator);   
    }
    else if(operator == 3)
    {
        multiply();
        operator = " * ";
        answer(operator);   
    }
    else if(operator == 4)
    {
        divide();
        operator = " / ";
        answer(operator);   
    }
    else if(operator == 5)
    {
        modulus();
        operator = " % ";
        answer(operator);   
    }
}

function add()
{
    total = number1 + number2;
}

function subtract()
{
    total = number1 - number2;
}

function multiply()
{
    total = number1 * number2;
}

function divide()
{
    total = number1 / number2;
}

function modulus()
{
    total = number1 % number2;
}

function answer(operator)
{
    alert("Your calculation was: " + number1 + operator + number2 + " = " + total);
}

function keepgoing()
{
    runagain = confirm("Would you like to make another calculation?");

    if(runagain === true)
    {
        main();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add the HTML?

Comment: you're changing the conditions of your `if()` chain. you test operator, and then CHANGE IT once a match is done. That's never a good idea, though in this case you lucked out and aren't changing it to somethign that'd affect actual operations.

Comment: A few suggestions: remove `operator` from your parameters to the `answer()` method.  It's already defined in the global scope.  Also, use a `switch` statement in your `assignment()` method instead of if/else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling answer() in this function:

```
function main()
{
inputNumbers();
assignment();
answer(); // <- here
keepgoing();
}
```

But you also call `assignment()`, which calls in return the `answer()` function:

```
function assignment()
{
    operator = parseInt(prompt("Enter a '1' for addition\n" + "Enter a '2' for subtraction\n" + "Enter a '3' for multiplication\n" + "Enter a '4' for division\n" + "Enter a '5' for modulus/remainder"));

    if(operator == 1)
    {
        add();
        operator = " + ";
        answer(operator); // <- here, and also in subsequents if/else blocks
    }

...
```

Side note: `parseInt` should always be used with the `parseInt(x,10)` parameter added if you mean to parse in decimal system.

Answer (score 2):

You're simply calling the `answer()` function twice. You shouldn't call it from your `main()` as it is the case where your variable (`operator`) is undefined.

Comment: Where? I know that's what's happening, but I don't understand where. I am knowingly calling it in main().

Comment: And in every assignment

Answer (score 0):

The first time it call's from **assignment** function when Operator is defined

the next time it is called from **main** function where operator is not defined

hence the error